# IgniteConfiguration properties - do these properties still exist?

Tags: gridgain, ignite

When porting from gridgain to ignite, I can't find matching properties for the following in IgniteConfiguration. Have they been totally purged or is there something else we should be using ?

```
<bean id="abstractGridConfiguration" abstract="true"
      class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
.......
<!--<property name="restEnabled" value="false"/>-->
<!--<property name="executorServiceShutdown" value="true"/>-->
<!--<property name="systemExecutorServiceShutdown" value="true"/>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable REST add this:

```
<property name="connectorConfiguration"><null/></property>
```

As for the thread pools, in Ignite you can only specify sizes (see `IgniteConfiguration.setXxxThreadPoolSize()` properties). Thus having shutdown flags doesn't make sense anymore.